# Holomorphic extension to a closed half-space

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology

While reading [D. Zagier's expository paper](http://mathdl.maa.org/images/upload_library/22/Chauvenet/Zagier.pdf) on the proof of the *prime number theorem* given by Newman, I encountered the following terminology problem : let $f$ be a holomorphic function defined in an open half-space $\Re(\sigma) > \sigma_0$. What does mean the sentence

> $f$ extends holomorphically to $\Re(\sigma) \geq \sigma_0$ ?

My guess would be that $f$ extends holomorphically to an open neighbourdhood of any $\sigma_0 + i\tau$ ($\tau \in \mathbb{R}$). Is that it ?

Using the fact that a holomorphic function has only finitely many zeros in a compact subset, this seems to be consistent with the paper, but this argument is not explicitely stated.

Comment: to my knowledge, the expression "extends holomprphically" is used with an open set. I agree that the term is ambiguous here and I think you are right in your interpretation

Comment: Yes, I would agree. In every context I have ever seen such a statement made, it means that $f$ extends holomorphically to a neighborhood of the set $\text{Re}(\sigma)\geqslant \sigma$.

Answer (score 1):

By convention, "$f$ is holomorphic on set $A$" means "$f$ is holomorphic on some open set $U$ such that $A\subseteq U$".

A function $f$, originally defined on a set $B$, extends to a holomorphic function on a larger set $A$, if there exists a function $F$ which is holomorphic on $A$, such that the restriction of $F$ to $B$ agrees with $f$.

I checked the paper and the usage there conforms to the above conventions. In particular, the proof of "Analytic theorem" makes this clear.